# UIViewController's delegate function which determines pop

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 ViewControllers in Navigation Stack, which are ViewControllerA, ViewControllerB & ViewControllerC.

When I press back button from ViewControllerB I reach to ViewControllerA.

I want to check how I reached to ViewControllerA whether by Popping back or as rootViewController of Navigation Stack.

Comment: Add the code that you have tried. This question contains way less information for anyone to help you.

Comment: What you want to do please explain

Answer (score 0):

you can give your backButton a unwind function and catch it in the view controller.

```
@IBAction func unwindToView(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let XControllerView = unwindSegue.sourceViewController as? XController {
        print("Coming from XControllerView")
    }
    else if let YControllerView = unwindSegue.sourceViewController as? YController {
        print("Coming from YControllerView")
    }
}
```

For more information about unwind : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621473-unwind

Answer (score 0):

Make a protocol:

```
protocol DismissProtocol{
func dismissPresentedViewControllerComplete()
}
```

We will make the viewControllerA conform to this protocol.

Make a property in ViewControllerB of type DismissProtocol.

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController{

var delegate: DismissProtocol?
//............

}
```

When you present your ViewControllerB, assign the ViewControllerA as the delegate.

```
class SecondController: UIViewController{
var delegate: DismissProtocol?
```

Override the protocol method in ViewControllerA:

```
extension ViewControllerA: DismissProtocol{
func dismissPresentedViewControllerComplete() {
    // Do what you want to do when you return from ViewControllerB
}
}
```

Now, in the ViewControllerB's dismiss completion, execute this override method:

```
        self.dismiss(animated: false) {
        self.delegate?.dismissPresentedViewControllerComplete()
    }
```